# MATERIAL CHIPS Change comma to space

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor

I use the material angular chips input.

I display data like that :

```
<div   [ngStyle]="{'font-size':'18px'}" *ngFor="let ppsToDisplay  of ppssToDisplay | async">
    <mat-list *ngIf="ppsToDisplay.effetsind" >Effets indésirables : <mat-chip-list>
            <mat-chip>  {{ ppsToDisplay?.effetsind }}</mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-list>
</div>
```

but i have just one big chips because i havent space between chips, just comma,

How i can change this ? thx

Comment: I don't understand what's the issue, here is a stackblitz with your code, does it reproduce the unwanted behavior ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51305989

Comment: my data display like that item1,item2,item3,item4, i want just item1, tem2, item3, item4,

Comment: It's really hard to understand, can you edit the stackblitz to reproduce your issue and add it to your question ?

Comment: I don't konw use stackblitz but i use angular material input chips. I can save on firebase data like that  1 : "item1" 2":item2" ....and when i display data i have item1,item2 and i just want item1, item2 with an additional space

Comment: You need to invest more effort if you want help from the community, your question is not clear enough.

Comment: ok i work for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are saying is that `ppsToDisplay.effetsind` is a string which is comma-separated ?

If I understood this correctly, this might solve it :

```
<div   [ngStyle]="{'font-size':'18px'}" *ngFor="let ppsToDisplay  of ppssToDisplay | async">
<mat-list *ngIf="ppsToDisplay.effetsind" >Effets indésirables : 
<mat-chip-list>
<mat-chip *ngFor="let effetsind of ppsToDisplay.effetsind.split(',')">  {{ effetsind }}
</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</mat-list>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't realy understand *ngFor="let effetsind of ppsToDisplay.effetsind.split(',')">  {{ effetsind }}

Comment: Say `ppsToDisplay.effetsind` is `effet1,effet2`, then `ppsToDisplay.effetsind.split(',')` would give you `['effet1','effet2']` so you can use `*ngFor` to loop though it. I'm not familiar with `mat-chip` I thought you wanted one `mat-chip` for every `'effet1','effet2'`

Comment: OK so `ppsToDisplay.effetsind` was already an array and not a string comma-separated. Glad it works now !